# Difference between `go print(v)` and `go func() { print(v) }()`?

Tags: pointers, go, closures

Here is the code:

```
type field struct {
    name string
}

func print(p *field) {
    fmt.Println(p.name)
}

func fix1() {
    data := []*field{{name: "one"}, {name: "two"}, {name: "three"}}
    for _, v := range data {
        go print(v)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 200)
}

func wrong1() {
    data := []*field{{name: "one"}, {name: "two"}, {name: "three"}}
    for _, v := range data {
        go func() {
            print(v)
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 200)
}

func main() {
    wrong1()
}
```

As far as I understand, all goroutines in function `wrong1` share the same local variable `v`. At the moment of a goroutine execution, the value of `v` may be equal to any value in `data`, therefore the function prints random data three times.

However, I am failing to understand why function `fix1` behaves differently (it prints each value in `data` exactly once).

Comment: Note: `print` is a Go built-in function: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#print To avoid confusion, please don't name your function `print`, It overrides the built-in function..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

#### wrong1(): `go func() { print(v) }()`

---

> [Go: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)
>
> Some confusion may arise when using closures with concurrency.
>   Consider the following program:
>
> ```
> func main() {
>     done := make(chan bool)
>
>     values := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
>     for _, v := range values {
>         go func() {
>             fmt.Println(v)
>             done <- true
>         }()
>     }
>
>     // wait for all goroutines to complete before exiting
>     for _ = range values {
>         <-done
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> One might mistakenly expect to see a, b, c as the output. What you'll
>   probably see instead is c, c, c. This is because each iteration of the
>   loop uses the same instance of the variable v, so each closure shares
>   that single variable. When the closure runs, it prints the value of v
>   at the time fmt.Println is executed, but v may have been modified
>   since the goroutine was launched.
>
> To bind the current value of v to each closure as it is launched, one
>   must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration.
>   One way is to pass the variable as an argument to the closure:
>
> ```
> for _, v := range values {
>     go func(u string) {
>         fmt.Println(u)
>         done <- true
>     }(v)
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the value of v is passed as an argument to the
>   anonymous function. That value is then accessible inside the function
>   as the variable u.
>
> Even easier is just to create a new variable, using a declaration
>   style that may seem odd but works fine in Go:
>
> ```
> for _, v := range values {
>     v := v // create a new 'v'.
>     go func() {
>         fmt.Println(v)
>         done <- true
>     }()
> }
> ```

---

Your `wrong1` example,

```
for _, v := range data {
    go func() {
        print(v)
    }()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0w86nvVMt1g

Output:

```
three
three
three
```

---

Your `wrong1` example, creating a new variable,

```
for _, v := range data {
    v := v
    go func() {
        print(v)
    }()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/z5RCI0ZZU8Z

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

---

Your `wrong1` example, passing the variable as an argument,

```
for _, v := range data {
    go func(v *field) {
        print(v)
    }(v)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/1JVI7XYSqvv

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

---

#### fix1(): `go print(v)`

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> Given an expression f of function type F,
>
> ```
> f(a1, a2, … an)
> ```
>
> calls f with arguments a1, a2, … an. Except for one special case,
>   arguments must be single-valued expressions assignable to the
>   parameter types of F and are evaluated before the function is called.
>
> [Go statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements)
>
> The function value and parameters are evaluated as usual in the
>   calling goroutine.

---

Your `fix1` example, evaluating the value of `v` before the function is called,

```
for _, v := range data {
    go print(v)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rN3UNaGi-ge

Output:

```
one
two
three
```